# Elegantly check whether the range between two variables is larger/smaller than 'x'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two variables, and I'd like to trigger some code if their values are within 5 numbers of each other. Not knowing which variable has the higher value, I could do something like this:

```
if (var1 > var2) {
  if ((var1 - var2) < 5) {
    // do code
  }
} else {
  if ((var2 - var1) < 5) {
    // do code
  }
}
```

This is bulky and I feel it is unecessary for such a task. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Math.abs()` to get the absolute value. That way you only need to know if the difference is between 0 and 5. Try this:

```
if (Math.abs(var1 - var2) < 5) {
  // do code
}
```

```js
[[0,10], [1,3], [2,10], [100,99], [1000,990]].forEach(function(arr) {
  if (Math.abs(arr[0] - arr[1]) < 5) {
    console.log(arr);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this solves the issue of checking for a negative. Appreciate the answer!